# Cakephp is trying to connect to my machine instead of the database I've setup

Tags: php, cakephp, mariadb, php-7

I'm having a hard time while trying to run a local project in my computer. It's built on cakephp 3.2.x, I run it with cakephp's dev server (bin/cake server), but the project crashes when it tries to paginate something for the user landing page:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'scqadev'@'192.168.1.63' (using password: YES)
```

Here comes the main headache: 192.168.1.63 is the IP of my computer, but my datasources aren't pointing to my machine. I want it to connect to a database in 192.168.1.43. Here's my config/app.php file:

```
 'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.1.43',
        'username' => 'scqadev',
        'password' => 'scqadev',
        'database' => 'scqadev',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
    'csd' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.1.43',
        //'port' => 'nonstandard_port_number',
        'username' => 'csd',
        'password' => 'csd',
        'database' => 'csd',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
],
```

The problem happens in this line, inside a controller:

```
 $this->set('analises', $this->paginate($this->Analises));
```

And my 'Analise' entity points to the default datasource (there is no custom datasource config in src/Model/Entity/Analise.php).

So where is this configuration coming from? Why is cakephp trying to log in my computer's database instead of 192.168.1.43's ?

Comment: It is connecting to the proper db. mysql accounts are `username@hostname`, where hostname is where the connection comes **FROM**, not where the connection is going to. So your scqadev@192.168.1.63 is an invalid account for your server at .43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not trying to connect to your computer.  The application is trying to connect to the correct datasource as `'scqadev'@'192.168.1.63'`.  You should make sure that such user is defined in your database.  Or (probably better) a user called `'scqadev'@'%'`.

Comment: For more security, use `'scqadev'@'192.168.%'`